# Regex expression to back reference more than 9 values in a replace

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I have a regex expression that traverses a string and pulls out 40 values, it looks sort if like the query below, but much larger and more complicated

```
est(.*)/test>test>(.*)<test><test>(.*)test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test><test>(.*)/test>
```

My question is how do I use these expressions with the replace command when the number exceeds 9. It seems as if whenever I use `\10` it returns the value for `\1` and then appends a `0` to the end.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks :)

Also I am using UEStudio, but if a different program does it better then no biggie :)

Comment: In Sublime Text, "\10" doesnt work either, but "$10" DOES WORK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Most of the simple Regex engines used by editors aren't equipped to handle more than 10 matching groups;</s> it doesn't seem like UltraEdit can.  I just tried Notepad++ and it won't even *match* a regex with 10 groups.

Your best bet, I think, is to write something fast in a quick language with a decent regex parser. **but that wouldn't answer the question as asked**

Here's something in Python:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)')
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = pattern.match(line)
        print m.groups()
```

Note that Python allows backreferences such as `\20`: in order to have a backreference to group 2 followed by a literal 0, you need to use `\g<2>0`, which is unambiguous.

Edit:
Most flavors of regex, and editors which include a regex engine, should follow the replace syntax as follows:

```
abcdefghijklmnop
search: (.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(?<name>.)(.)
note:    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
value:   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m
replace result:
    \11      k1      i.e.: match 1, then the character "1"
    ${12}    l       most should support this
    ${name}  l       few support named references, but use them where you can.
```

Named references are usually only possible in very specific flavor of regex libraries, test your tool to know for sure.

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

the above quote never seemed so true :(

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 16):

As pointed out by [psycho brm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304283/regex-expression-to-replace-over-10-values#comment18908030_3304283):
Use $10 instead of \10
I am using notepad++ and it works beautifull.

Comment: Works on Sublime. Possibly on some others. Does anyone know what standard this $ notation is a part of?

Answer (score 3):

put a $ in front of the double digit subgroup:  e.g. \1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9$10 It worked for me.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the tip. This works very well in Notepad++ :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using named groups; so instead of the tenth:

```
(.*)
```

use:

```
(?<group10>.*)
```

and then use the following replace string:

```
${group10}
```

(That's of course in the absence of a better solution using looping, and remember that there might be different regex syntax flavours depending on your environment.)

Comment: This worked for me when using regex matching in nginx, which doesn't seem to like matching more than 9 groups. Same issue the OP has where $10 is interpreted as $1 + 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot handle more than 9 subgroups why not initially match groups of 9 and then loop and apply regexes to those matches?

i.e. first match `(<test.*/test>)+` and then for each subgroup match on `<test(.*)/test>`.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case that would not work, the pattern is pretty big. However I appreciate the suggestion. Thanks :)